# Could anyone tell me the method that import *** which *** is a variable in Ironpython?

Tags: import, ironpython

I would like to import another script file inside a script file which both are in Ironpython.
For example:

```
`filename = "C:\test.py"
import filename`
```

And I got an error said:

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named filename

Could you tell me how to import a module if it is put into a variable?

Of course I know, there is no any problem if I write it like following:

```
import test
```

But it is necessary that the module is immutable, which is actually not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually standard Python - the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function is what you want.